# Search in Mysql database on selected rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to do a query using mysqli prepared statement in PHP.
I want to do search using keyword on selected rows only.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT complaint_id 
                              FROM complaints WHERE user_id = ? 
                              AND status IN (?,?) AND 
                              complaint_id IN ( SELECT complaint_id FROM complaints Where MATCH (body) AGAINST ( ? )) 
                              ORDER BY user_id ASC");
$stmt->bind_param("iiis", $user_id,$status1,$status2,$keyword);
```

I know that I need to do a subquery. But can anyone explain what will be format of doing subquery or is my approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do a subquery at all. Just add the other condition to your select statement like:

```sql
SELECT complaint_id 
    FROM complaints WHERE user_id = ? 
    AND status IN (?,?) AND 
    MATCH (body) AGAINST ( ? )
    ORDER BY user_id ASC
```

The result will be the same as you will be limiting records that have the user_id, status, and body match.

Also, make sure you have a full text index on your column by running this SQL:

```sql
ALTER TABLE complaints ADD FULLTEXT(body);
```

Comment: I got a error during executing above statement "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list"